# Way to make a POST request to server to INSERT a record and retrieve the generated ID in the Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am developing an app with the following tables: Clients | Transports. Client_Id is a foreign key into Transports.
I have to make a creation wizard for transports where in the first step I maybe need to create a client and pass client_id in the next step via React state. What I want to achieve is to POST my server to create the client and in the same request retrieve the generated client_id.

Thats my backend code:

```
    exports.createClient = function(req,res,next){
    const text = 'INSERT INTO public.client (name, "isCompany", mobile, phone, email, tax_code, addr) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING id'
    const values = [req.body.name,req.body.isCompany,req.body.mobile,req.body.phone,req.body.email,req.body.tax_code,req.body.addr];
    DBclient.query(text,values,function(err,result){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        res.sendStatus(200).send(result.rows[0].id);
    });
};
```

And here I try to retrieve the response:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.state.client_name);
        formData.append('isCompany', this.state.client_isCompany);
        formData.append('tax_code', this.state.client_tax_code);
        formData.append('addr', this.state.client_addr);
        formData.append('phone', this.state.client_phone);
        formData.append('mobile', this.state.client_mobile);
        formData.append('email', this.state.client_email);
        await fetch(clienturl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(data => this.setState({client_id:data}));
```

Here is my state after :
[console log output for state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWOX1.png)

I would be grateful if someone can help to this.

Comment: So you received the response just fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Notice you're not [checking the response for error and reading its body](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) yet.

Comment: Whats the correct way of reading the body of response?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the int value that server successfully returns

Comment: Add `.then(res => { if (res.ok) return res.text(); else throw new Error("HTTP "+res.status); })` after the `fetch()` call

Comment: have you try client_id: data.response?

Comment: @Bergi  that grants me a promise which is pending. Still cannot receive the value of client_id.

Comment: @ChrisChen client_id is undefined after this

Comment: @leo.nanos check the response in console.log and in postman first. it may caused by wrong Content-Type in headers from your client-side script.

Comment: @ChrisChen I found it using the debugging. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Several tries using postman and console.log() debugging, I realised that the problem was on server side while I wasnt setting the body of my response. On postman I saw that server was only responding with status code (200 OK). The update that maked this work is :

```
DBclient.query(text,values,function(err,result){
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }   
    res.status(200).send({client_id : result.rows[0].id});
});
```